# Tracking all server side actions on Angular Js UI

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

I need to show all server side REST actions on angular js UI in my application.
Like when the user is created, I need to show User is created/failed immediately on the panel on GUI.

I am saving all such actions in DB table(Recent Activity).I need to fetch data from DB table and show it on UI.

One way to design it get latest data from DB table(Recent Activity) on every action on the UI but for that, I need to make REST call on each action which is not very maintainable code.

What is the best way to design/implement above problem in angular js?

P.S. Application backend is implemented in Springboot

Answer (score 0):

When you will create a user, you are going to hit a create User API and that API will return HTTP response.

So you can check if you get a success, just notify user a success message else failure message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. I am saving all actions in DB because when user will login in application he should be able to track all activities of past few days.

Comment: then you have to fetch the activities from DB and display it using angular